# "..the card that was given to her.." or "...the card given to her.."

Tags: passive-voice

So I've been reading a novel and found this:

> "Tara Burgness does not realize until after she has returned to London that the address on the card **given to her** by Mr.Barris is not a private residence.."

Since the text in bold is a passive voice, shouldn't it be *that was given to her* ? If the former is correct, why?

Comment: _That_ or _which was given to her_ would be correct, but there is nothing wrong with  leaving them out if the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Given*" is the past participle of "*to give*". Past participles can directly modify nouns, so there's no reason to use a clause with a relative pronoun to create passive voice.

"*I replaced my laptop's broken battery.*" sounds better to me than "*I replaced my laptop's battery that was broken.*" as well as "*Walking on frozen rivers can be dangerous.*" sounds better to me than "*Walking on rivers that are frozen can be dangerous.*" All four sentences are grammatically correct, but using fewer words is generally better.